# Hamburger Menu & Overflow menu keep disappearing

Tags: codenameone

I am building an app in codenameone, and I am having issues with hamburger menu and overflow menu, they keep disappearing on some pages, sometimes they are there and sometimes they are gone

See attached image, these two menus keep going and coming sometimes in the app

[image]

Is there a way out?

I am using the Toolbar API to add commands

```
tb = new Toolbar(); 
tb.getStyle().setBgImage(new RR().getR().getImage("newmenuimage.png"));
tb.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
f.setToolbar(tb);
```

Comment: How are you adding your commands?

Comment: I am using a toolbar system

Comment: tb = new Toolbar();
        tb.getStyle().setBgImage(new RR().getR().getImage("newmenuimage.png"));
        tb.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.setToolbar(tb);

Comment: Is there a reason for setting the background image? Why not just style your TitleArea in the GUI Builder. Also, Toolbar is already a BorderLayout container.

Comment: OK i remove the setlayout and also the background image, cause i am no more using a background for it

Comment: "hambuRgEr menu" ;)

Comment: I have seen this when going back a form and not re-creating the back form. When I make sure the back form is re-created it works. Maybe this is your problem.

Comment: ok, thanks, but how can i re-create the back form?, can you show me how you did it?, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add a theme Constant **commandBehaviour** if it doesn't already exist and set it to `Side` and make sure your **sideMenuImage** has a valid image name as a value. Do the same for **menuImage** which is for the overflow menu.

Customise `TitleArea` and set its border to Empty and Under `color`, uncheck `Derive Transparency` and set it to 255 and uncheck `Derive Background` and set it to the color of your choice (ensure there's contrast between this color and your menu images).

Comment: The command behavior is best left undefined, I would also suggest making sure that if you changed the UIID of the Form or redefined it that you make sure the transparency is 255.

Comment: Thanks shai, i am making changes regarding all your advice,